# How to filter DynamoDb by object property value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table:
[image]

How shoul I filter entried in DB table where all keys are: access.role = "ADMIN"?

Answer (score 1):

You would be best served by setting up an Global Index (GSI). You set the Partition Key equal to that attribute, and the Sort Key equal to some other attribute that you can guarantee will be unique. Then you use your SDK of choice or the Query option in the console, select the index, and query for partion_key = ADMIN

However. Be aware. Index's are a complete replication of the table. Dynamo is *very* good at this and relatively fast at doing so, but there is still the possibility that your index will be out of sync with the actual data. If you are not making the call against the index very often you are pretty much fine. If you are calling it very often, then you should restructure your table.

Dynamo is not an SQL. When setting up a dynamo schema you have to consider how you will access your data. your Access Patterns. You should design your data with your Partition Key as the data you will have when looking up (Ie: i always will have a user ID number) and your sort keys as the individual documents related to that PK (ie: a user has a document that is his profile data, a document that is his profile picture url, a document that is a list of his friends user numbers, a document that is ... ect)

Then you use Indexs for things like your question that you wont be doing very often.